# How to write if else condition in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following sql, how can i add if-else like control structure.

```
SELECT
        tblcabbooking.id AS id,
        concat(tblcabstatus.`status`,' ',
        ifnull(concat("(INR",tblbookingcharges.totalbill,")"),'')) AS `status`, 
        tblcomplaint.id AS com_id,
        tblcomplaint.statusid AS com_status,
        tblcabbooking.csr_id AS emp,
        concat(tblcabbooking.dropaddress,tblcabbooking.droparea) AS drop_area,
        tblbookingcharges.totalbill, 
        tblcabbooking.booking_reference AS ref,
        tblmasterpackage.master_package AS booking_type,
        concat(tblcabbooking.pickupdate," ",tblcabbooking.pickuptime) AS ordertime,
        concat(tblclient.clientname," ",tblappid.`type`) AS partner,
        concat(tblcablistmgmt.NAME,', ',tbldriver.firstname,"(",tbldriver.contactno,")") AS vehicle, 
        concat(tbluserinfo.firstname,"(",tbluserinfo.mobno,")") AS clientname, 
        concat(tbldriver.firstname," ",tbldriver.contactno) AS driver_name,
        tblcabbooking.mobileno AS mob_no,
        tbluserinfo.uid AS client_id,
        tbldriver.uid AS driver_id,
        concat(tblcabbooking.pickupaddress,' ',tblcabbooking.pickuparea) AS departure,
        tbldriver.vehicleregistrationno AS reg
    FROM      tblcabbooking 
    JOIN      tblcabstatus 
    ON        tblcabbooking.`status`=tblcabstatus.`status_id` 
    JOIN      tbluserinfo 
    ON        tbluserinfo.uid=tblcabbooking.clientid 
    JOIN      tblmasterpackage 
    ON        tblcabbooking.bookingtype=tblmasterpackage.package_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbldriver 
    ON        tblcabbooking.pickup=tbldriver.uid 
    LEFT JOIN tblcablistmgmt 
    ON        tbldriver.typeofvehicle=tblcablistmgmt.id 
    JOIN      tblappid 
    ON        tblappid.id=tblcabbooking.partner 
    JOIN      tblclient 
    ON        tblappid.clientid=tblclient.id 
    LEFT JOIN tblbookingcharges 
    ON        tblcabbooking.id=tblbookingcharges.bookingid 
    LEFT JOIN tblcomplaint 
    ON        tblcabbooking.id=tblcomplaint.bookingid 
    WHERE     tblcabbooking.bookingdate >= fromdate 
    AND       tblcabbooking.bookingdate <= todate 
    AND       tblcabbooking.mobileno=ifnull(callerid,tblcabbooking.mobileno) 
    AND       tblcabbooking.booking_reference=ifnull(book_ref, tblcabbooking.booking_reference) 
    AND       tbldriver.vehicleregistrationno=ifnull(vehicle_number, tbldriver.vehicleregistrationno)
    AND       tbldriver.firstname=ifnull(vehicle_driver, tbldriver.firstname)IF partnertype LIKE 'Android Booking' then
    AND 
    tblcabbooking.devicetype='ANDROID' 
    ELSE 
    IF partnertype LIKE 'Web Booking' then 
    AND 
    tblcabbooking.devicetype='WEB' 
    ELSE 
    IF partnertype LIKE 'Call Center Booking' then 
    AND 
    tblcabbooking.devicetype='0' 
    ELSE 
    and 
    partnertype=tblcabbooking.devicetype 
    END 
    IF ORDER BY tblcabbooking.id DESC ;
```

Comment: how to use set of string those change the query.

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, move your conditions for these table from WHERE to ON, to get true outer join. (As it is now, these joins executes as regular inner joins.)

Answer (score 3):

NO, you can't use `IF .. ELSE` construct in normal ANSI SQL query, but you can rewrite it using `CASE` statement like

```
WHERE tblcabbooking.devicetype = 
                CASE WHEN partnertype LIKE 'Android Booking' 
                THEN 'ANDROID' ELSE 'Web Booking'
```

Comment: we are insert to this code in above for if else condition it will show error :-                   tblcabbooking.devicetype = 
       CASE WHEN partnertype LIKE 'Android Booking'  THEN 'ANDROID' 
               else  CASE WHEN partnertype LIKE 'Web Booking'  THEN 'WEB' 
      else CASE WHEN partnertype LIKE 'Call Center Booking'  THEN '0' 
           else  THEN tblcabbooking.devicetype order by tblcabbooking.id desc;